# How to get a text channel by its id?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

`guild.get_channel()` returns a `GuildChannel`, and I need to get a `TextChannel`.
I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get_channel()` does return a `GuildChannel`, that's right. But, the `GuildChannel` is going to be one of the following, depending on what channel's ID you use:

- [`TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel)
- [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel)
- [`CategoryChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel)

So your method of getting the channel is absolutely correct - just make sure you're putting in the correct text channel's ID into the method so your return type will end up being a `TextChannel`:

For example, if my text channel ID was `112233445566778899`, then `channel` would contain a `TextChannel` object:

```py
channel = ctx.guild.get_channel(112233445566778899)
```

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel)

  [image]

  ---
- [`abc.GuildChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel) - This is an "Abstract Base Class" (hence abc). Other objects will inherit from this, that's all it is, just a skeleton for other objects to build on top of.
  They'll all share the same attributes as `abc.GuildChannel`, but they'll also have their own, such as `VoiceChannel` which has a `connect()` coroutine that the other channels don't have.

  [image]

  ---
- And some proof of concept:

  [image]

Comment: Yes, that helped me. But, I want to receive a message from this channel, but the None object is being returned. As I read in the documentation .last_message is not reliable, so I will try another way. I will write as soon as I get the result

Comment: I forgot to write a little. Yes, another way to get the message helped me. Thank.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Good luck with the rest of your bot :^)